# Pine: how to use label.new for a specific chart (when plotting the chart and an indicator below)

Tags: pine-script

I would like to plot the index of the last bar ("5830", see screenshot below) on the prices chart instead of on the CCI chart.

Here is my code so far:

```
//@version=5
indicator("Mon script", overlay=false)

// CCI

cciSource = input.source(close, "Source CCI")
cci=ta.cci(close, 20)

plot(bar_index % 2 ? na: 100, color=color.gray, style=plot.style_linebr)
plot(bar_index % 2 ? na: -100, color=color.gray, style=plot.style_linebr)
plot(cci, title="CCI",color=color.fuchsia)


if (barstate.islast)
    label.new(bar_index, open, str.tostring(bar_index, format.mintick), yloc = yloc.belowbar, style = label.style_none, textcolor = color.black, size = size.normal)
```

[image]

Any idea on how to do this ?

Best regards

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You already used label, so change the indicator properties to `overlay=true`

```
//@version=5
indicator("Mon script", overlay=true)

// CCI

cciSource = input.source(close, "Source CCI")
cci=ta.cci(close, 20)


if (barstate.islast)
    label.new(bar_index, low, str.tostring(bar_index, format.mintick), yloc = yloc.belowbar, style = label.style_label_up, textcolor = color.white, size = size.normal)
```

Also, you can make it as table

```
//@version=5
indicator("Mon script", overlay=true)

// CCI

cciSource = input.source(close, "Source CCI")
cci=ta.cci(close, 20)


var table table1 = na
var table2 = table.new(position.top_left, na, na)
if barstate.islastconfirmedhistory
    var table3 = table.new(position = position.top_right, columns = 1, rows = 1, bgcolor = color.yellow, border_width = 1)
    table.cell(table_id = table3, column = 0, row = 0, text = str.tostring(bar_index, format.mintick))
```

Comment: User specifically asked to plot to main chart, example is for plotting everything to main chart which the user explicitely did not ask for.